# Quartz Job @ExecuteInJTATransaction - failed to get UserTransaction in wildfly 10

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, wildfly-10

I have a Quartz Job Listener that persists information about the job's execution. 
I'm using jta-datasource and my job class was annotated with @ExecuteInJTATransaction.

When Job Listener is invoked, the follow error occurs:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: 
UserTransactionHelper could not lookup/create UserTransaction. 
[See nested exception:javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:java:comp/UserTransaction]
```

My environment is Wildfly-10.0 and Quartz-2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misssed a propertiy in quartz.properties file. Add following line in your quartz.properties file and I am sure your problem will be resolved.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.userTransactionURL=java:jboss/UserTransaction
```